# NStimer animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to make 4 buttons, which are arranged 2x2. And when we press anyone of them, they change places in a circle. How make this animation by NSTimer?

Comment: Why would you need an NSTimer for this type of animation? Your buttons will send a callback whenever they are pressed, as long as you link a function to them, and that function can handle the animation, without a timer.

Comment: May be, but it is my task to make it use NSTimer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you can do is create a custom view, and use an NSTimer to call a function that will incrementally change the frames of the buttons, moving them in whatever fashion you want. The only thing is that most of that is already built into the already existing animation stuff.

Comment: message me your email and I will give some old code I made when I was just starting iOS development

Comment: I sent you an email containing that example project